# Calculate area of HTML element on website?

Tags: c#, html, css, perl, scrape

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to calculate the area of a `HTML element` on a website? In pixels, as a percentage or whatever.

My first thoughts have been to make the assumption that the  element is 100% in width and height, and then try to retrieve the size through a mapping between the `HTML and CSS`.

So if there's a width/height attribute in the referenced CSS-file I could possibly say that 
the body element is covered by a column that takes 25% of the area (everything is based on your screen resolution of course - and I'm still trying to figure out how I'd be able to do this programmatically).

Or whether I should render the website and do my calculations based on an image with the most common screen resolution at the time).

Are there any more possible solutions?

(Currently I'm trying to solve this in Perl, but I suppose any language that's got a library for this purpose would be appreciated to know about!)

---

**EDIT:** I need to retrieve the visual area for every single element on a page. 
For example; if there are elements on top of the `<body>` element, that covers it visually, I want to exclude that area from the `<body>`'s and so on. A simple raytracing to find the visible area for every element on a page.

---

**EDIT:** Let's say we exclude JavaScript - any other approaches possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve through this? If you describe the problem space then may be someone can provide a solution you haven't thought of.

Comment: Doing this is trivial. Doing it without using Javascript is insane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I would use jQuery - even if you don't use a library, your best bet will be a JavaScript solution.

```
var $elt = $('#some-element-id'),
    height = $elt.height(),
    width = $elt.width(),
    area = height * width; // contains the area in px^2
```

http://api.jquery.com/height and http://api.jquery.com/width

Comment: Can JQuery retrieve the area for any possible html element, even if none have been stated in CSS?

Comment: Would it be possible to write a JQuery script to take input from stdin and output to stdout or send it to a database? Something tells me that Node.js + JQuery.js are my knights in shining armour?

Comment: @Zolomon: sounds reasonable enough. I'm not sure if Nodejs gets you a DOM out-of-the-box, though, and you definitely need one for that. Thing is, you **also** need a CSS engine, and different browsers render the same input (at least slightly) differently.

Answer (score 3):

This is such a simple problem I don't think JQuery is necessary if you are not already using it.

Try running this:

```
<div id="myParent">
   What's up?
   <div id="myDiv">Hello there!</div>
</div>
```

With

```
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    alert(myDiv.offsetHeight);
    alert(myDiv.offsetWidth);

    var myParent = myDiv.parentNode;
    alert(myParent.offsetHeight);
    alert(myParent.offsetWidth);
```

Divide resulting widths to get % of space the element takes in it's parent, or simply use the absolute pixel values.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery to do it if possible.

alert('Size: ' + $('li').size());

http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: Size() doesn't measure elements, it counts the number of occurrences of a particular element. http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 0):

Would it be feasible to use javascript?  If so you can get the width/height with something like this:

```
document.getElementById(YourElementsId).style.height;
document.getElementById(YourElementsId).style.width;
```

However this does depening on how the elements are sytled in the first place.  Another option would be

```
document.getElementById(YourElementsId).clientHeight;
document.getElementById(YourElementsId).clientWidth;
```